# update datatable with select

Tags: mysql, sql

How to Update a Table with Select in where clause

EXAMPLE:

```
UPDATE
    cp_asseteventinquiry
SET
    cp_asseteventinquiry.Due_Date = date_format (curdate(), '%m/%d/%Y')

Where (Results of Below Query )
```

---

```
SELECT 
    Distinct(TopLevelAsset_Num) 
FROM cp_asseteventinquiry
WHERE 
    cp_asseteventinquiry.History='NO'
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * 
        FROM flightlogs 
        WHERE 
            flightlogs.Asset=cp_asseteventinquiry.TopLevelAsset_Num 
            AND flightlogs.Scheduled_Date=date_format (curdate(), '%m/%d/%Y')
    );
```

Comment: Please choose 1 DBMS.  Are you working with MySql or SqlServer?

Comment: Why are there parens around `TopLevelAsset_Num` in the SELECT statement? Why are date values being stored in columns that are character datatype, rather than `DATE` datatype? Why is there a space between the function name `DATE_FORMAT` and the paren?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` instead:

```
UPDATE cp_asseteventinquiry ai LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT TopLevelAsset_Num
        FROM cp_asseteventinquiry ai2
        WHERE ai2.History = 'NO' AND
              NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM flightlogs fl
                          WHERE fl.Asset = ai2.TopLevelAsset_Num  AND
                                fl.Scheduled_Date = curdate()
                         )
      ) tai
      ON ai.TopLevelAsset_Num = ai2.TopLevelAsset_Num
    SET ai.Due_Date = curdate()
WHERE ai2.TopLevelAsset_Num IS NULL;
```

The bigger issue is why you are formatting dates as a string.  Always store dates in the database using native formats.  If you *have* to store dates as a string, then use yyyy-mm-dd format, so the string can be ordered correctly.

Comment: The Requirement is Get the list of Items which needs to be updated by using select query , Then update the items which are the results of Select Query

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but you could use a query like this:

```
UPDATE cp_asseteventinquiry a
  LEFT
  JOIN flightlogs f
    ON f.Asset = a.TopLevelAsset_Num
   AND f.Scheduled_Date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y')
   SET a.Due_Date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y')
 WHERE a.History='NO'
   AND f.Asset IS NULL
```

To set the `Due_Date` column on every row that has a value of `'NO'` in the `History` column, and that doesn't have any corresponding row in the `flightlogs` table that satisfies the specified conditions.

It's not at all clear why you are needing to format dates in a specific format, unless these are being stored in character type columns, which is downright bizarre, considering that MySQL has a datatype custom designed for storing date values, the `DATE` datatype.

---

**NOTE:** Don't put parens around expressions where they aren't necessary, especially if they don't add any meaning. For example, the parens in this context have no meaning:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TopLevelAsset_Num) ...
```

That's equivalent to what we normally use,

```
SELECT DISTINCT TopLevelAsset_Num ...
```

(The addition of parens confusingly make it look as if DISTINCT is a function that takes an argument. DISTINCT isn't a function, it's a keyword. And it applies to all expressions in the SELECT list, it makes no difference whether columns are wrapped in parens.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The only reason I can see for you get a distinct list of `TopLevelAsset_Num`, is that some of the rows with the same value have `History='NO'` and other's don't. And you want to update *all* rows with a matching `TopLevelAsset_Num`.

In that case, use an inline view to get the list, and perform a join operation:

```
UPDATE cp_asseteventinquiry a
  JOIN ( SELECT n.TopLevelAsset_Num
           FROM cp_asseteventinquiry n
           LEFT
           JOIN flightlogs f
             ON f.Asset = n.TopLevelAsset_Num
            AND f.Scheduled_Date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y')
          WHERE n.History='NO'
            AND f.Asset IS NULL
       ) v
    ON v.TopLevelAsset_Num = a.TopLevelAsset_Num
   SET a.Due_Date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear !! A  select query gives the lists of items which need to be update and the Update query should pick up the results of Select Query.